# simple Previous/Next buttons

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm triying to paginate the response of an API. This API, have 15 items per page.

Actualy, i'm  using something like this:

```
vm.next = function(currentPage){
$http.get('/api?page='+vm.firstPage++)
.then(function(data){
               vm.chuck = data.data.Response;
               });
          }

vm.previous = function(currentPage){
$http.get('/api?page='+vm.firstPage--)
.then(function(data){
               vm.chuck = data.data.Response;
               });
          }
```

and

```
vm.firstPage = 1;
```

My html view for buttons:

```
<div class="text-center">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="$ctrl.previous()">Previous</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="$ctrl.next()">Next</button>
</div>
```

The idea was to had the increment/decrement on every click. It works, but only after the second click. Also, if i change the value of `vm.firstPage` to `2`, it works since the very first click, but when i click Previous, it becomes a mess.

What can i do to have the increment/decrement on the buttons?

I'm using AngularJs and javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's about the operator precedence. Make vm.firstPage++/vm.firstPage-- before API call

```
vm.next = function(currentPage){
vm.firstPage++;
$http.get('/api?page='+vm.firstPage)
.then(function(data){
           vm.chuck = data.data.Response;
           });
      }
```